# I need to prevent deletion or editing but allow downloading

Tags: google-drive, sharing

I have a directory on Google Drive that contains many files. I need people to be able to download any file but not to delete or alter the originals. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

- right-click on the folder
- select **Share...**
- select **Advanced**
- select **Change...**
- select **On - Anyone with the link**
- hit **<kbd>Save</kbd>** button
- hit **<kbd>Done</kbd>** button

---

[image: 9]